# Setting Gradient Background programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have an image on which I'm putting a colored overlay, like this (the colors are taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7323234/977890)):

layout/list_item_view.xml

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/image_cover_gradient"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue"        
    />
```

drawable/gradient_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="@color/CornflowerBlue"
            android:endColor="@color/Transparent"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

This always puts a blue overlay (CornflowerBlue) and it works as expected.

Now I'm trying to do this programatically and followed some stackoverflow answers (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348761/977890)), but still can't make it work. Here's my code:

```
private void setColor(int color){
    View gradientCover = view.findViewById(R.id.image_cover_gradient);
    // this FAILS because it's a StateListDrawable
    //GradientDrawable coverGd = (GradientDrawable) gradientCover.getBackground();
    //coverGd.setColor(color);

    //this doesn't seem to work either (I don't see any effect on the image)
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(
            Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[] { color, resources.getColor(R.color.Transparent) 
            });
    StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
    sld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.startColor, android.R.attr.endColor}, drawable);
    gradientCover.setBackground(sld);
}
```

Comment: get rid of StateListDrawable,  all you need is GradientDrawable

Comment: Kotlin code for whom may need it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495750/6247186

Answer (score 11):

As @pskink suggested - removing the StateListDrawable solved it:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(
    Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[] { color, resources.getColor(R.color.Transparent) 
});     
gradientCover.setBackground(drawable);
```